# UITableView reloadData method crashes app

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

In my view controller, I have an array that continuously add objects to. There's also a tableView in the same view. I want to populate the tableView and update it as the array gets updated.

```
// Defines the table
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

// Defines the table - Customize the number of rows in the table view.
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.items.count;
}

 // Fill the table - Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]
                initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    if (self.items && self.items.count > 0) {
        BulkItem *item = [self.items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        if (item) {
            // Cell Title Text

            //            // define the range you're interested in
            //            NSRange stringRange = {0, MIN([asset.name length], 1)};
            //            // adjust the range to include dependent chars
            //            stringRange = [asset.name rangeOfComposedCharacterSequencesForRange:stringRange];
            //            // Now you can create the short string
            //            NSString *typeSubstring = [[asset.name uppercaseString] substringWithRange:stringRange];

            //    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@", typeSubstring, asset.name];
            cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithString:item.bulkItemMaster.name];

        }
    }

    return cell;
}
```

When the array is updated, I use:

```
[self.itemTableView reloadData];
```

To update the tableView. However, after I get to this part of my code, it crashes. It gives me this error message:

```
"2014-12-09 23:07:28.156 va-std[750:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSPlaceholderString initWithString:]: nil argument'"
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: `item.bulkItemMaster.name` is nil.

Comment: `item.bulkItemMaster.name` is nil

Comment: Check your datasource array `item.bulkItemMaster.name` according to the updation .

Answer (score 0):

This line is a nightmare,

```
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithString:item.bulkItemMaster.name];
```

before assigning name to the label, check for not nil.

```
if(item.bulkItemMaster.name) {
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithString:item.bulkItemMaster.name];
}
```